# javascript onclick call to function

Tags: javascript, this

I'm in the process of learning javascript and was looking at this code:

```
function foo1 {
  var curObj = this;

    this.foo2 = function() {
         curObj.test = "foo2";
    }

    this.foo3 = function() {
         curObj.test = "foo3";
    }

  // called by
  x.on("click", curObj.foo1)
  x.on("click", curObj.foo2)
}
```

the "foo2" and "foo3" functions are repetitive so I'd like to replace them with something like:

```
function setTest(foo) {
  curObj.test = foo;
}

function foo1 {
  var curObj.test;
  x.on("click", setTest(foo));
}
```

So my question is how do I pass curObj to the function setTest, x.onClick = setTest(this, foo) doesn't working. What if I want to modify other curObj values within the function setTest(), would something like "this" cover that? Is "this" a reference to a memory address or just an object id?

You guys are awesome, thanks for any help you are willing to provide!

Comment: `function foo1 {` should be `function foo1 (){`, it is a syntax error, or a typo. You set these values directly: `this.test = "foo1"` are you trying to use private variables?

Comment: no, but I am trying to reference the curObj var that is within foo1 scope, in setTest. Does that make sense? I'd like to pass the curObj to setTest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the `call()` function

```
function testThis () {
  console.log(this);
}

testThis.call(curObj) // prints curObj
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call